# How to retrieve data from firebase

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase. This is my database. How do i retrieve this data from firebase. This data is being added by the user so i dont know the number of incubators.

```
{
  Incubators :
            {
                Name_of_Incubator1
                { 
                      Contact : 3443354684
                      Founder : "Atul"
                      Email : "xyz@gmail.com"
                  }
                 Name_of_Incubator2
                { 
                      Contact : 3444569684
                      Founder : "Anupis"
                      Email : "xyz24@gmail.com"
                  }
                 .
                 . 
                 .
                 .
           }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An example from [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once):

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
// ...
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
    Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
    // ...
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    // Getting Post failed, log a message
    Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    // ...
}
};
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

You can try this sample project for starting up with Firebase : [Friendly Chat](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/)